# Awarding accept answer for endings and analysis

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, analysis

The climax in some movies are interpreted differently by different people. When a question related to the ending of movies like [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/226/scene-during-the-ending-of-the-shining) is asked. What are the important points to be considered when accepting an answer.

**UPDATE**

The question also applies for analysis of movies, [example here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-has-the-greatest-chance-of-being-in-marcellus-wallaces-briefcase-in-pulp-f).

Comment: That's probably not a good example since a) it has only one answer, and b) the answer quotes the director, so it's not very subjective. :)

Comment: @Flimzy: you are right, it was actually something that struck me while I was reading the answer to my question. Please provide a link to a better example if you stumble upon one.

Comment: There you go http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-has-the-greatest-chance-of-being-in-marcellus-wallaces-briefcase-in-pulp-f but it's not really ending but same idea, different interpretation sort of stuff.

Comment: Good question - very hard to answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way you look at it, while you may not agree with an 'accepted' ending, it is that user's discretion to accept the answer, and that's how it has always been on any of the SE sites.  I do agree with Mnementh that it needs to have some type of change, and with our community specifically, having an **asker accepted answer** and a **community accepted answer** could be one way of implementing it.  The argument can be made that this is the reason for votes and not always is it the case that the accepted answer is the most voted for answer.  But having some kind of visual indicator would be nice.

TL;DR

Its the way it is, if you like an answer more than the accepted, vote for it and don't vote for the accepted, it is the asker's discretion what is the 'accepted' vs what it might actually be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I get more and more the impression, that accept is no good feature for SE-sites, in fact it may even be harmful. As I started on Stackoverflow, it seemed reasonable. I have a problem, someone have a solution, I accept this answer. But it often happens, that days later someone posts a better answer. I may miss it, because I'm sometimes inactive for weeks. So the not so good answer is accepted, the better is not, although it gets more votes with the time. Accepts are actually harmful.

I start to think, that no question exists, that has only one correct answer.

Anyways, the system is like it is, and accepts give much reputation (even ignoring the cap) and your accept-rate is part of the user-card. So it is no option to avoid accepts altogether. So what can we do with question, there multiple good answers can be given.

First, if actually after some time only one good answer exists, I give it the accept. If multiple exists, I may choose one, mostly the one giving the best references. I sometimes comment to point out other answers, that I also considered for the accept.

Comment: If you notice a different, better answer to your question as time goes on, you CAN unaccept the currently accepted answer and accept a new one. "Accept" is not a permanent/static action.

Comment: I know, but as I'm often inactive for some weeks, I can miss that. That applies more to other users, who go permanently inactive.

Comment: @Mnementh: your answer seems generic to all stackexchange sites. I was looking for something specific to the movies site.