# What do with an obviously wrong answer marked as correct?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

This is in regards to this question:

[How historically accurate is the TV series Spartacus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/how-historically-accurate-is-the-tv-series-spartacus)

It might be just me misunderstanding the accepted answer, but it seems to me that it relies on parody article from somethingawful.com as fact. Even though it does link to a second more factual article.

What's the policy on this sort of thing?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-should-we-do-about-questions-marked-correct-that-have-obviously-incorrect-a?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I covered something similar a [while back](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/203/130) that accepted answers are by the asker's discretion.

The only other power *anyone* has short of developers changing it in the system Databases is voting.  If you feel this is wrong, downvote and explain why and maybe even come up with a better answer that you feel is much more accurate.

I can't speak for the accuracy because I don't know that period of history, nor have I watched that series.  And even so, my only powers would be the same.  The only advantage moderators have in that regard in answer *control* is deleting answers, but that should be reserved for spam answers and those that are essentially comments anyway, not *wrong* answers.  That is what voting is for.

Comment: +1 for coming up with a better answer. One of my favorite things abt any Stack site is the challenge of coming up with a better answer.